# python: Numeric to Binary Converter goes wild with big numbers

Tags: python

I have built this program to calculate binary numbers as an exercise and it does so reliably for small numbers. At an unforseeable point however it starts to give weird outputs. Maybe someone more experienced than me finds the problem:

(the program takes in a number: then for as long as "num" is bigger than 1 finds the largest base2 that fits in it, calculates the binary for that base 2, subtracts the base2 from num and then repeats the process, adding all of the binarys together until num <= 1, if num ==1 it then adds 1 more)

Thanks a lot!

````
#find largest base 2 that fits in num, subtract - again
#build binary from the largest to smallest part of base2
def getlargestpart(num):
    base2 = 1
    base2len = 0
    while num >= base2:
        base2 = base2 * 2
        base2len = base2len + 1

    base2len = base2len - 1 #backtracking (whileloop overshoots)
    base2 = base2/2

    if base2 == 0.5:
        return 0, base2len
    else:
        return base2, base2len # biggest part of num

def getbinary(num):
    #init step
    base2, base2len = getlargestpart(num)
    bin = 10
    if base2 != 0:
        while base2len != 0:
            bin = bin * 10
            base2len = base2len - 1
        bin = bin/ 10 #one too much
    else:
        bin = 0
    
    return bin, base2

def calcfullbinary(num):
    #setup
    bin = 0
    #create bin
    while num > 1:
        tempbin, base2 = getbinary(num)
        bin = bin + tempbin
        num = num - base2
    if num == 1:
        bin = bin + 1
    return bin


#run
num = int(input("Enter a number (int): "))
print(num)
bin = int(calcfullbinary(num))
print(bin)```
````

Comment: Thank you I will try that, but theoretically, unless it maxes out the data storage for int, that shouldn't be a problem right? or can something else happen there?

Comment: It's not about the data storage for int, it's possible about the overall memory, and the calculation time. I don't know the implementation of arbitrary precision integers to answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divisions in your program result in a float type, even if the answer is an integer. Use integer division, with the double slash: `a // b`.

The reason this happens is because Python uses 64 bit floating point types, which have limited precision. But for integers, it can use arbitrary precision, so sticking to integers everywhere in your calculation should make this correct.

To solve this in your code, replace

```
base2len = base2len - 1 #backtracking (whileloop overshoots)
base2 = base2/2

if base2 == 0.5:
    return 0, base2len
else:
    return base2, base2len # biggest part of num
```

with

```
base2len = base2len - 1 #backtracking (whileloop overshoots)

if base2 == 1:
    return 0, base2len
else:
    return base2 // 2, base2len # biggest part of num
```

Note: `base2 = base2/2` is removed, and integer division is used in the last line.

Also replace

```
bin = bin/ 10
```

with

```
bin = bin // 10
```

(or

```
bin //= 10
```

)